# how to write a complex form of setTimeOut and setTimeInterval with and without recursion?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
function sayHello() {
  alert('Hello');
}
setTimeout(sayHello, 1000);
```

This is a basic setTimeout example, but can I get an in-depth explanation like a long one how it works with recursion and without recursion in javascript? (visualization helps as snippet code too)

Comment: recursion? like adding `setTimeout(sayHello, 1000);` inside `sayHello`?

Comment: Yes, something like that or like the user calls the function it prints out hello, then prints out world (after a specific amount of time).

Comment: sure, you can do that, just call a different function inside sayHello setTimeout - the possibilities are endless

Comment: Can I get a more complex explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `setTimeout()` again inside the callback. This will print `Hello` in 1 second, then print `World` 2 seconds after that.

```js
function sayHello() {
  console.log('Hello');
  setTimeout(sayWorld, 2000);
}

function sayWorld() {
  console.log('World');
}

setTimeout(sayHello, 1000);
```